# How to create a folder outside of the main installation directory?

Tags: wix

I am writing a small installer and I want to make a directory on a partition `D:` besides the main installation folder is on partition `C:`. How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe similar question could give a hint - [WIX: copy file to custom dir in another partition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902980/wix-copy-file-to-custom-dir-in-another-partition)

Comment: Similar question regarding creating folders: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860731/how-to-create-a-directory-in-wix

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have two root directories in WIX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269990/is-it-possible-to-have-two-root-directories-in-wix)